# Can a UIWebView be a "Buy Now" option in iOS or does that violate the TOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, in-app-purchase

I have an app that displays products for a client. The user has the option of clicking a "Buy it now" button, which pops up a UIWebView and loads a link to the clients website allowing the user to complete the transaction with out leaving the app, but as I started thinking about this I was curious if this violates the Apple TOS

11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected

Since the user is buying a product rather then content, functionality, or services is this an acceptable use of the UIWebView, or will this get the app rejected?

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is allowed as long as you sell physical goods (eg. like the Amazon window shopper app)

Comment: Thank  you for the quick response, Is this actually documented in any where, or just the way their current wording works out?

Comment: @Nathan Now that you mention it... I was fairly sure that it is in the guidelines, but I can't find it there anymore. However, I know that there are quite a few apps that take eg. your credit card and let you buy physical goods.

Comment: Thanks Sid - I appreciate your assistance.